# CA2202 CA2215 HttpApplication Dispose base call

Tags: c#, dispose, httpapplication, ca2202

I am currently getting the [CA2202](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182334.aspx) (*Do not dispose objects multiple times*) on code that I am analysing. The warning refers to `HttpApplication.Dispose` method that I am overriding. I know the `IDispose.Dipose` method should not be virtual or be overriden but this a result of Microsoft implementing the `IDispose.Dispose` as virtual in the `HttpApplication` class and not providing a virtual protected Dispose method.

The warning appears to be complaining about the calling of the `base.Dispose` method. I am calling the base Dispose method in case the base class needs to close or dispose of any objects. And also suspect that I'll probably end up with the [CA2215](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182330.aspx) (*Dispose methods should call base class dispose*) warning otherwise.

Does anyone know why I am getting this (CA2202) warning and what to do about it?

I am tempted to suppress it but the [MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182334.aspx) says that it should never be suppressed.

The sub class looks like the following (it has been shortened for brevity and you can assume that the `_container` field has been initialised):

```
public class MyHttpApplication : HttpApplication
{
    private bool _disposed;
    private IDisposable _container;

    public sealed override void Dispose()
    {
        if (_disposed)
            return;
        try
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
        finally
        {
            //The following lines is what causes the CA2202 code analysis warning
            base.Dispose();
        }

    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (_disposed)
            return;

        try
        {
            if (disposing && _container != null)
            {
                _container.Dispose();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            _disposed = true;
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems there's no way out without suppressing something. My solution was to put the call to base.Dispose() inside the Dispose(bool) method then suppress CA2215, for which the [MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182330.aspx) say "It is safe to suppress a warning from this rule if the call to base.Dispose occurs at a deeper calling level than the rule checks."

```
[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2215:Dispose methods should call base class dispose", Justification = "base.Dispose() is called from Dispose(bool)")]
public sealed override void Dispose()
{
    if (_disposed)
        return;
    Dispose(true);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}

protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (_disposed)
        return;

    try
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            base.Dispose();
            if (_container != null)
            {
                _container.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        _disposed = true;
    }
}
```